# NPSP: Why is Meta Deploy telling me I don't have the right permissions?

Tags: package-install

I'm using Meta Deploy to install the Enhanced Recurring Donations in production in an org I work with. I am getting an error message that says I don't have the permissions necessary to do the install. I have a System Admin profile with all the default permissions there. What could be preventing this install?

Thanks in advance!
Trish Perkin

Comment: Hi Trish - I would suggest sharing this question in the Power of Us Hub; there's a much more focused group of expertise around Enhanced Recurring Donations and its installer there.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidReed